# GUI bulk rename tool for linux

Tags: filemanager

So I've been using OSX but have been using Ubuntu on my mac desktop for a good 2 weeks. I am wondering if anyone has a suggestion for an alternative program for bulk file/folder renaming?

I'm currently using [this program (A Better Finder Rename)](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) and I can rename files like this way

```
parent1
  -- sub1
    -- parent1-sub1-my-file-here0001.jpg
    -- parent1-sub1-my-file-here0002.jpg
```

or do find and replace text like replace all instances of "image" with "IMAGE" or change the file extension to something.

I've read old discussions on this topic but the suggestions made are really quite basic compared to what I'm used to.

I've thought of scripting some of the more easier bits like creating a sequence for the files but honestly, I prefer to use a GUI for things like this.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

edit: the topic that's supposedly the "original" of this one is date 2010. A lot of new tools could've come out since then.

Comment: At least on Xubuntu, selecting multiple files in the file manager, right-clicking, and selecting "Rename" allow bulk renaming.

Comment: You may want to check out Thunar Bulk Rename utility http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/22/bulk-renaming-made-easy-with-thunar-bulk-renamer/ . I am running XFCE with the Thunar file manager, so your needs may be different. I may post a longer answer later.

Comment: I've seen that as I've ran Xubuntu (which uses Thunar file manager) but I don't think it can rename files based on parent folders?

Comment: dated 2010. how can it be a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be best I don't know but I always prefer terminal for that.

As you specified GUI I refer to use **KRENAME**. It renames all types of files and especially Track, year,genre,... can be easily edited for  music and Exif for images.